# Save a workspace and open it on another computer

Tags: r, model, random-forest, environment, rpart

I created a model (a tree object from a random forest) working on a old version of R (1.0.136) because the package (`reprtree`) I needed didn't work on the new version.

Now I want to analyse my model using more recent packages (`rpart.plot`), which is only possible on a more recent version of R, so on another computer.

Is there a way to save the environment and open it in the other session?

Comment: Just a minor note: I think you're probably confusing your R version with your RStudio version. R version 1.2 was released in 2001, so unless you are *extremely* out of date, 1.0.136 is probably not your R version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `save.image()` should create a file that is **forward-compatible**, i.e. you can create it with an older version of R and load it in a newer version (use `load()` to restore it on the far end).

There was a change in the save format around R version 3.5.0 (I believe the version number you gave above is an **RStudio** version number, which is probably irrelevant here ...) Unless you specify `version=2` when saving on a more recent (>3.5) R version, your image will not be *backward* compatible to older R versions.

Comment: Of course this is dependent on the objects created  by the old version of `reprtree` being compatible with the newer versions of `rpart.plot`. No good way to find that out except to try!

Comment: if this solved your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it (you may have to wait a little while). Note that "thank-you" comments are actually deprecated on SO (as being "noise"), but the spirit is still appreciated